# I have an error log comming which i am not getting or understand in Python

Tags: python, berkeley-db, error-log, bsddb

My code is running properly. I have a code in which user adds data into the Berkeley db. When i checked my error log, i am not getting understand to what does this error mean.

One error log is checked about File permission deneid. I had gicen my db file a permission, but about other error log i am not understanding

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/bsddb/__init__.py", line 306, in hashopen, referer: http://192.168.2.181/~neeraj/

d.open(file, db.DB_HASH, flags, mode), referer: http://192.168.2.181/~neeraj/

DBAccessError, referer: http://192.168.2.181/~neeraj/

(13, 'Permission denied'), referer: http://192.168.2.181/~neeraj/

File does not exist: /usr/local/Apache2.2.17/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`favicon.ico` is automatically requested by browsers to determine what icon to show for a page in the browser (e.g. in the tab or window header). You can safely ignore errors related to it if you haven't created an icon for your page, or you can simply create a `favicon.ico` file and place it in your root serving directory to make the error go away.

Comment: Which does exist by default (on creation of a new project under GAE)

Comment: Thank you. What about others ?